# InnoDB: Is a covering index in the form of (PK, col1, col2, col3) redundant?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, clustered-index

Table structure for `config`:

- property (primary key)
- value
- description

Query:

```
SELECT property, value FROM config
```

If I put a covering index on `(property, value)` the optimizer still chooses the `PRIMARY` index, but the `extra` in `EXPLAIN` is `NULL`. If I tell the optimizer to use my covering index, the `extra` in `EXPLAIN` is `USING INDEX`.

What's really happening here? Why is the optimizer choosing the `PRIMARY` index over my covering index by default? Am I avoiding disk IO by telling the optimizer to use my covering index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRIMARY index in InnoDB is a tree where the primary key field (`property`) is a key and remaining columns are the value. In a secondary index the key are the index fields and the value is a primary key. In your case the secondary index has fields (`property`, `value`, and `property`). (`property`, `value`) is a key and `property` is a value.
The secondary index is larger and redundant, so MySQL make a right decision to use the PRIMARY index.

Check out a presentation I gave on InnoDB indexes structure for more details.
https://www.slideshare.net/akuzminsky/efficient-indexes-in-mysql

Comment: Many thanks, will check that out. I discovered that I can use `(value)` effectively as a covering index since it contains fields `(value, property)`. What I'm still confused about is what exactly is buffered into memory for the PK: is it just `property` with a pointer to the full row on disk, or is the `value` column also buffered into memory (I'm excluding `description` because it is actually secretly a `TEXT` column).

Comment: Also, is there perhaps a video somewhere of your presentation? Would absolutely be interested in watching that. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't ask what storage engine you use. I assumed InnoDB, but it could be MyISAM. Each of them use different caching approach.
Here's a video from a meetup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytW1KV_lIbQ

Comment: Yes, using InnoDB. Checking out the video now, thanks.

Comment: InnoDB caches all pages it reads from the disk in the buffer pool. So, after `SELECT property, value FROM config` it will cache all primary index.   `description ` is a different story. if it's stored in-page it will be cached. If it's stored in external pages (which is a case for large (>7k) values) then only a beginning (768 or 20 bytes depending on whether it's COMPACT or DYNAMIC format) will be cached.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that was the case. I probably have a lot of redundant indexes to go through and eliminate now. Much appreciated, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @akuzminsky - Only the used blocks of an index (secondary or PRIMARY) are cached.  It does not necessarily cache all the index.

Comment: @Dan - more on redundancy in indexes -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql .  That also explains some simple techniques for deciding what indexes to have.  (This is better than simply throwing lots of indexes on a table -- most will never be used.)

Comment: @RickJames , you should read more carefully. After full index/table scan all pages of the index will be in the BP.

Comment: @akuzminsky - Oops.  But still, that is not quite correct.  If the index/table is bigger then the buffer_pool, the scan will _read_ all of the blocks, but only some of the blocks will _remain_ in the BP.